# In a question, I am asked that x is a 3-dimensional vector of 1s. Can someone tell me how I would write x in matlab function?

Tags: function, matlab

I need to write a MATLAB code for what i am asked to define x, which is 3 dimensional vector of ones. how would i write it?

```
x= ones()
```

Comment: Please read the documentation before asking a question here. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ones.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**General Form:**

```
x = ones(D1,D2,D3,D4 ...DN);
```

`D1` → The size of the 1st dimension. 
`D2` → The size of the 2nd dimension. 
`D3` → The size of the 3rd dimension. 
`DN` → The size of the nth dimension.

---

### 3 × 1:

```
Number_Of_Rows = 3;
Number_Of_Columns = 1;
x = ones(Number_Of_Rows,Number_Of_Columns)
```

[image: 3 By 1]

---

### 3 × 3:

```
Number_Of_Rows = 3;
Number_Of_Columns = 3;
x = ones(Number_Of_Rows,Number_Of_Columns)
```

or

```
x = ones(3)
```

[image: 3 By 3]

---

### 3 × 3 × 3:

```
Number_Of_Rows = 3;
Number_Of_Columns = 3;
Number_Of_Layers = 3;
x = ones(Number_Of_Rows,Number_Of_Columns,Number_Of_Layers)
```

[image: 3 By 3 By 3]

Layer 1/Channel 1 → `x(:,:,1)` 
Layer 2/Channel 2 → `x(:,:,2)` 
Layer 3/Channel 3 → `x(:,:,3)`

The colon `:` indicates to take all the elements in the specific dimension.

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: That’s a lot of effort just to reproduce what is already in the documentation. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ones.html I strongly recommend that you don’t bother with questions like these, it’s not worth your time.

Comment: @CrisLuengo May bad, next time I'll point towards the documentation in a comment for the more trivial type of questions.

Comment: Don’t get me wrong, you do good work, I’ve upvoted quite a few of your answers. And you’re allowed to waste as much time as you like. I just prefer seeing you put your time into things that add information to the internet. But it’s your own choice to make, of course.

Answer (score 2):

In case you mean a 3D-vector:

```
x = ones(3, 1);
```

But I guess you probably mean a 3D tensor, so try this:

```
x = ones(4, 5, 6);
```

Comment: Just in case he needs matrix x=ones(3,3)